# SCSS - Hover on button with SVG has an unintended delay effect

Tags: html, css, user-interface, web, sass

I have a Button that contains an SVG icon element. When hovering over it, I want to recolor both, the SVG icon and the text. My SCSS looks like so:

```
&.btn-highlight-green {
    color: $color-green;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid $color-green;

    > svg {
        color: $color-green;
    }

    &:hover {
        color: $color-green-dark;
        border: 1px solid $color-green;
        background-color: $color-green-light;

        > svg {
           color: $color-green-dark;
        }
    }
}
```

It does what I intend, but when I hover, first the svg icon is recolored, and then with a delay of  <1 sec the text is recolored. How can I avoid that effect? especially when only quickly hovering over it it basically only recolors the svg.

Comment: yes I'm using ant-design

Comment: Are you using any framework? There isn't in this SCSS anything that would explain that delay but maybe it is in the frameworks stylesheets. You could try to override it with transition-property: none;

Comment: adding the transition properties worked! thanks. If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as the right one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using any framework? There isn't in this SCSS anything that would explain that delay but maybe it is in the frameworks stylesheets. You could try to override it with `transition-property: none;`